# Ways to remove duplicate data in MongoDB by using Python 3

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I manage to find all duplicates in my MongoDB by using Python 3 script.

```
duplicates = keywordsCollection.aggregate([{"$group":{"_id":"$keyword", "dups":{"$push":"$_id"}, "count": {"$sum": 1}}},
{"$match":{"count": {"$gt": 1}}}
])


print(list(duplicates))
```

Here's the result when I run the script :

```
[{'_id': 'computer', 'dups': [ObjectId('600c40b31cc42f9c113f4d6a'), ObjectId('600c40b31cc42f9c113f4d6d')], 'count': 2}, {'_id': 'software computer', 'dups': [ObjectId('600c40b31cc42f9c113f4d67'), ObjectId('600c40b31cc42f9c113f4d68')], 'count': 2}]
```

Now what I need to do is to delete those `duplicates data`.I've tried :

```
db.keywords.aggregate([{$group:{_id:"$keyword", dups:{$push:"$_id"}, count: {$sum: 1}}},
{$match:{count: {$gt: 1}}}
]).forEach(function(doc){
  doc.dups.shift();
  db.dups.remove({_id : {$in: doc.dups}});
});
```

When I run the command it's having error saying that it needs to try converting to array before calling foreach.I'm aware that `dropDups:true` is not able to use in Python 3.Is there any other way to remove the duplicate data other than foreach method?Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried `set()` instead of `list()` ?
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets

```
duplicates = keywordsCollection.aggregate([{"$group":{"_id":"$keyword", "dups":{"$push":"$_id"}, "count": {"$sum": 1}}},
{"$match":{"count": {"$gt": 1}}}
])


print(set(duplicates))
```

Should return only distinct entries, so if something is already in the set, a duplicate shouldn't be included.

Comment: I haven't try set before and if I use set instead of list , I'm getting error in the python script

Comment: if `list(duplicates)` works, try `set(list(duplicates))`.